# Search for files in a case insensitive manner?

Tags: php, glob

I have the following code witch finds files in my apache server in a recursive way:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['q'])) {
    $query = $_GET['q'];
    foreach (glob("*/*{$query}*") as $filename) {
    echo "<th class=\"icon\"><img src=\"/.res/save.png\"></th><th><a href=\"{$filename}\">{$filename}</a><th class=\"desc\"><a href=\"#open-modal\" onclick=\"loadDoc('{$filename}')\"><img src=\"/.res/info.png\"></a></th></tr>";
 }
}
?>
```

So, when I type the following in my adress bar: `http://mywebsite.org/file.php?q=File+Name`, I get a list of all the files in my server named "File Name.whatever". Sadly, when I ask for "fILE nAme", it doesnt finds it, since its cAse SenSItiVe.

I also tried the following code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['q'])) {
    $query = $_GET['q'];
    $cmd2 = shell_exec("find . \( ! -regex '.*/\..*' \) -type f -iname \"*{$query}*\"");
$divide2 = explode("./", $cmd2);
 unset($divide2[0]);
    if(empty($divide2))
    echo "<center><p>No results for: \"{$query}\".</p></center>";
    else foreach( $divide2 as $path2 ) { echo "<th class=\"icon\"><img src=\"/.res/save.png\"></th><th><a href=\"{$path2}\">{$path2}</a></th></tr>";
 }
}
?>
```

It searches for files in a case insensitive manner. (Yay!), but im really concerned about security, since im allowing users to input whatever they want inside a shell command... They could input `&& destroy-server` haha

Im still searching for an answer, but if someone here knows how to solve my problem, ill be more than happy!
Cheers.

Comment: I'd ask myself if I really need this feature. And if yes, rather risk having a longer search and use smth like RecursiveDirectoryIterator and search myself to avoid using shell_exec.

Comment: At first I'd start sanitizing the use input - in any case.

Comment: you  could use globs character classes to build a case insensitive search. loop the search string say its "fILE nAme" and build the glob search [fF][iI][lL]...

Comment: @tim But the user will have to input [fF][iI][lL]... everytime they make a search! Not good..

Comment: @Jeff I *really* need this feature. Im making an auto indexer... The search bar is a must-have. Duckduckgo cannot crawl trough my website since im password-protecting my folders.

Comment: no, you build that string from the users input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$split=str_split($_GET['q']);//split each letter

$query='';
foreach($split as $b){ //loop
    if(ctype_alpha($b)){//check its a letter
      $query.='['.strtoupper($b).strtolower($b).']';//build upercase\lower case pair
      }else{//if not a letter use raw version
      $query.=$b;
     }
}
```

then as you already have ..

```
foreach (glob("{$query}") as $filename) {
```